# How do I capture when a finger touches the screen and when a finger is removed from a screen on touchscreen device

Tags: jquery, firefox, touchscreen

I am developing an app for a touchscreen and I would like to capture the equivalent of the mouse down and mouse up events.

For example, when the user has their finger touching the screen, a javascript function will execute, but when the finger leaves the screen function stops.

I am using firefox 3.5, with the jQuery framework for my javascript.

Thanks for any help,
Ben

Answer (score 2):

Just use jQuery [mousedown](http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/) and [mouseup](http://api.jquery.com/mouseup/).

There are no specific events for using a finger, because all the finger actions do are to fire the mouse events on the page:

```
$(document).mousedown(function(e) {
   alert("Finger is Down");
});

$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
   alert("Finger is Up");
});
```

Comment: This is what I originally tried before posting the question. The mouseup event doesnt get fired when the finger leaves the screen

Comment: Perhaps you should updated your question with some code and show it now working.

Answer (score 1):

The **touchstart** event fires when a finger touches the screen no matter if the user is going to tap or scroll. *mousedown* does not work in these cases.

```
$(document).on('touchstart', 'body', function(){
  alert("Screen touched");
});
```

I do not know any event that fires when a finger leaves the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably interested in the `touchcancel` event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchcancel.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this jQuery plugin](http://code.google.com/p/touchpoint/) can help you.